# Wing IDE trouble with quotes

Tags: python, wing-ide

I've been trying to learn Python, but ran into a very interesting problem. I cannot seem to find the right double quotation marks to denote a string.

```
print(¨Hello, World!¨)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
Syntax Error: print(¨Hello, World!¨): <string>, line 113
```

Those funny marks are as close as I could get. This only seems to be happening in Wing IDE. Thoughts?

Comment: Odd, not something I've seen before.  Are you pressing the quote character on the keyboard and it's producing this incorrect character?  If so, please let us know which Wing IDE version this is, what OS you're on, and what type of keyboard you have.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Wing IDE 101 version 4.1.14-1 on Windows 7. Using an Asus laptop, G73Jh.

Comment: Switching the keyboard language seems to have sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it looks similar to the double-quote, `¨` is not a double-quote. It seems somehow your IDE is translating a double-quote into `¨` (a different character).

Comment: Seems to be a general problem with this model of laptop. Switching the keyboard language sorted out the problem.